¿Como ejecutar evento de checkbox desde el constructo?
Estoy haciendo un proyecto, en el cual quiero hacer que cuando se abra un JInternalFrame, este se abra con un CheckBox Seleccionado y cargue los datos correspondientes.

Quiero hacer que se abra con el checkbox Activos seleccionado. Pero no encuentro la manera de hacerlo correctamente.
Este es código que tengo en los checkbox:
private void cBoxActivos(boolean bEstatus)
{
    if(bEstatus)
    {
        bEstatus = false;
        cBox_Completos.setSelected(false);
    }
    else
    {
        bEstatus = false;
        cBox_Completos.setSelected(bEstatus);
        estatus = "1";
        CargarDatosTabla();
    }
}

Lo que hace es que deselecciona un checkbox si se selecciona otro.
He intentado poniendo en el constructor la siguientes lineas:
cBox_Activos.setSelected(true);
cBoxActivos(false);

Pero si lo hago de esta manera, tengo que darle click al checkbox "Activos" para poder hacer que funcione el de "Completos".
También me encontre uno que decía que se podía invocar el evento en construcor de la siguiente manera:
cBox_ActivosActionPerformed(new java.awt.event.ActionEvent(cBox_Activos, ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, ""));

Pero simplemente no funciono.
